# Plotting data in QISKit using plot_histogram

Tags: programming, qiskit

I'm trying to plot a set of data using `plot_histogram`, but the rendered image looks like this (the larger values are outside the image): 
 [image]

How can I set the y-axis to contain larger values? Or, is there any alternative way to avoid this problem? I have tried the `figsize(,)` [option](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/master/qiskit/basics/plotting_data_in_qiskit.ipynb) but it isn't effective.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in the `plot_histogram` function. I pushed a fix for it here: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/pull/1661 In the meantime you can probably workaround this locally by doing something like:

```
fig = plot_histogram(data)
ax = fig.axes[0]
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
fig.savefig('output.png') # Or whatever you doing to output the image
```

Which will adjust the y axis boundaries to be between 0 and 1.